# installation problem - nodejs-lts (exited 1603) - Error while running 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\nodejs-lts\tools\chocolateyinstall.ps1'

Tags: node.js, react-native, chocolatey, choco

I'm trying to create an android emulator for react-native, but I'm having some trouble installing some packages when I type in this command: `choco install -y nodejs-lts openjdk11`

You will find the above command at the following website: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup

nodejs-lts won't install for some reason. Do I have to uninstall nodejs and install nodejs-lts instead? Here is a screenshot of the error:
[image]

Comment: uninstall before installing if installed in you machine then restart you r machine and try it

Comment: @NensiKasundra I will try that.

Comment: @Nensi Kasundra It didn't work.

Comment: install node and android studio separately

Comment: then start Android Emulator from android studio and check

Comment: @Nensi Kasundra My android emulator on android studio already works and I have node and android studio separated already.

Comment: Have you tried doing what is suggested in the output from Chocolatey? i.e. inspect the log file from the installation attempt and check what it says.

Comment: @Gary Ewan Park I was looking at it and it didn't look like it had any errors.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall NodeJS manually and then run the command again.

[source](https://github.com/chocolatey/choco/issues/1525#issuecomment-616566842)

Answer (score -1):

check whether your system has C:\ProgramData,
If not that means its hidden which is causing the system to throw the error,
To fix-
It is generally not recommended to alter some system files-nevertheless.First of all

open File Explorer options from Control Panel
Then to View Tab.
Uncheck "Hide protected Operating system files" and click on "Show hidden files and folders"
Press Yes and then OK.

After this try to install it again and it'll work this time

Comment: Unfortunately this answer is totally unrelated to what the OP is asking, but welcome to SO!

Comment: I had the same error and this is what worked

Answer (score -1):

just open the power shell and run as administrator and the files will get installed